# Why my function cause crash when I run that function again?

Tags: php, function, crash

I'm trying to figure out why this loop doesn't work...

When I call `URLRedirect($MAPA, $URL, 0)` inside this same function it cause error... I want loop till every URL[*] is tested....

```
$var=URLRedirect($MAPA,$URL,0);
$Obsah=$var[0]; #Contend for page
$StyleSheet=$var[1]; #Style for page
$LoadError=$var[2]; #In case of error remove JS and CSS
if($Obsah==null){
    print("Content for page wasn't found");
}

/*Redirect to specific page*/
function URLRedirect($MAPA,$URL,$i){
    /*Inner function for map decode*/
    function MapGen($MAPA,$URL,$i){
        for ($x=0;$x<=$i;$x++){
            $MAPA=$MAPA[$URL[$x]];
        }
        return($MAPA);
    }
    /*Inner function for generation contend per page*/
    function ObsahGen($MAPA,$URL,$i,$value){
        for ($x=0;$x<=$i;$x++){
            $MAPA=$MAPA[$URL[$x]];
        }
        $MAPA=$MAPA[$value];
        return($MAPA);
    }
    
    if(MapGen($MAPA,$URL,$i)){ #Check if page exist level 0
        if($URL[$i+1]){ #Check if childs are requested 
            if(MapGen($MAPA,$URL,$i+1)){ #check if child exist
                URLRedirect($MAPA,$URL,$i+1); #Run loop that cause crash :(
            }
            else{ #Else redirect to previous page 
                for($x=0;$x<=$i;$x++){
                    $Adress.=$URL[$x];
                }
                $Adress="https://dreamli.net/".$Adress;
                $LoadError=1;
                header("Location: ".$Adress);
            }
        }
        else{ #If Not child website is requested show content for parent 
            $Obsah=ObsahGen($MAPA,$URL,$i,"obsah");
            $Style=ObsahGen($MAPA,$URL,$i,"style"); 
        }
    }
    else{ #If main page wasnt found redirect to error
        $Obsah="./Index/PHP/Error.php";
        $LoadError=1;
        header('Location: https://dreamli.net/');
    }
    $var=array($Obsah,$Style,$LoadError);
    return($var);
}
```

I'm new to php so I don't know about error reporting or something that could help me handle this error... strange is that is cause error only if conditions for it are right... So it must be something in loop that cause this...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+enable+error+reporting - it's not hard to find out how to enable error messages to be shown

Comment: Can you show sample values for `$MAPA` and `$URL`? What is the expected result?